# Different output when running command in bash script vs terminal

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep, command

When I run the following code in a bash script I receive an output of 2

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                       
HIPPO=$(ps -a | grep hippo | wc -l)                                                                                                                                                 
echo "$HIPPO"
```

However when I run the command `ps -a | grep hippo | wc -l` straight from a command prompt I get an output of 0

Reading the documentation on `ps` particularly the `-a` flag, I'm not understanding why the output is different.

Comment: Depending on the timing, `ps` might or might not list the `grep hippo` process (and maybe a subshell created to run the pipeline) in its output. All sorts of things can affect the timing. Try using `grep '[h]ippo` instead, since it won't match itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is called your script? If you named it with **hippo**, it will count in your **ps** call.

Comment: This appeared to be it.  And I'm guessing based on Gordon Davisson's comment above that something with timing was the reason that it was showing a count of 2 instead of 1?

Comment: Yes, I think for the other +1, it was about timing.

Answer (score 0):

https://superuser.com/questions/935374/difference-between-and-in-shell-script

When you do the command substitution, the command gets runs once according to the above. So I am assuming, the echo is picking a zombie process that ran that command.